# Definition collapses

Tags: siunitx

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper]{mwrep} 

\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\usepackage{amsmath}                        

\def\m3h{\: \frac{\SI{m^3}}{\SI{\hour}}}
\def\metrh{\: \frac{m^3}{h}}
\def\metre{\: \si{\metre}}


\begin{document}

$\m3h$
$\metreh$
$\metre$

\end{document}
```

Out of these three `\metreh` and `\metre` are working, but `\m3h` don't. 
The log reads:

```
! siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
!
! Invalid token 'm' in numerical input.
```

Comment: you can not have digits in command names

Comment: `\SI{m^3}` is wrong anyway. You mean `\si{\meter\cubed}`, most likely

Comment: no, it works perfectly fine in other parts of the code. The problem is with number in definition, but I have several others defs with numbers and they work xD @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer why bother writing `\meter\cubed` when you can write `\m^3`? What does that actually mean it's not recommended if it works?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sir, it yields [the same](http://i.imgur.com/BTqCgp8.png) result, so what's the ACTUAL difference?

Comment: @devloon: Well, I leave this to you then. If you insist in using `siunitx` wrongly it is your decision.

Comment: You should be using `\si` instead of `\SI` regardless. `\SI` takes in two arguments, not one.

Answer (score 2):

The macro `\m` is used inside arguments to `\SI` or `\si` as an abbreviation for `\metre`.

With `\def\m3h{...}` you are redefining `\m`. Yes, it's a rule of TeX that macro names can only consist either of a single nonalphabetic character or of one or more alphabetic (`a-z` and `A-Z`) characters.

Your `\def` defines `\m` and requires it is always followed by the tokens `3h`.

Please, try

```
\def\m3h{foo}
\def\m4a{baz}

\m3h
```

and enjoy the errors.

Besides, `\SI` takes ***two*** arguments. If you just want to print a unit, use `\si{<unit>}`.

Comment: Note that `\m` is an abbreviation for `\metre`, which is the official spelling for the unit. The macro `\meter` is provided only as in the US it is very unusual to see the correct spelling of the unit even in technical work.

Comment: @JosephWright - There's spectre/specter, calibre/caliber, etc. Why treat metre/meter any differently? Having lived many years in the US myself (though I don't live there at present), I can tell you that most Americans would consider "metre" to be the UK-English spelling variant of a unit of length they confidently believe ought to be spelled as "meter"...

Comment: @Mico THE BIPM, who _define_ the standard, are quite clear on this: for the SI unit it's 'metre'. In the same way, when writing technical material I have to write 'sulfur' even though that's 'wrong' in UK English, since the IUPAC have resolved that the spelling uses 'f'.

Comment: @JosephWright That's debatable: in Italy we call the unit *metro* and nobody can say anything about it.

Comment: @egreg The standard is written in English and French: I can't answer for other languages

Comment: @JosephWright - Note that I wasn't claiming that the standard-setting body's choice of spelling of the unit of length isn't "metre". All I was suggesting is, nobody should be surprised to find out that Americans will most likely react with an incredulous stare (probably followed immediately by a polite chuckle) to being informed that "meter" is *not* an appropriate spelling of the unit of length, not even in technical treatises... OK, time to upvote this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Digits can't be used in `\newcommand` macro names, there's only a bypass solution with `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse` which does not really has any advantage.

I also don't recommend `\def\foo100{...}` usages.

Don't use it ;-)

There are also errors in the usage of `siunitx` commands like `\si` and `\SI`.

Use `\si` if you want to use the unit alone, i.e. without numbers unlike `1,45 m`

I also don't recommend such things as `\frac{\si...}{\si...} at all.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper]{mwrep} 

\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\usepackage{amsmath}                        

%\def\m3h{\: \frac{\SI{m^3}}{\SI{\hour}}}
%\def\metrh{\: \frac{m^3}{h}}
%\def\metre{\: \si{\metre}}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{m3h}{\: \frac{\si{\meter\cubed}}{\si{\hour}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Use  \si{\meter\cubed}
\makeatletter
$\@nameuse{m3h}$
\makeatother



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have several other defs with numbers in them and they work, so I thought that's not the case.